# How to use vue-country-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add this

https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-country-select

in my profile.vue component, which have syntax like

```
<template>
<div id="myid">
</div>
</template>

...
export default {
...
}
```

When I putting just html-elements like this

```
<vue-country-select class="vue-country-select" name="country-select"
                    :model.sync="result" language="en-US">
</vue-country-select>
```

, there are mistake

*Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?*

Then I added code to my js-part

```
export default {
  components: {
    'vue-country-select': require('vue-country-select')
  },
  data () {
    return {
      result: null,
    ...
```

Then I have mistake

*Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.*

I googled and found, that there must be "default" word in router file, like this

```
{ path: '/profile',
  component: Profile**.default**,
  name: 'Profile',
  beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated
},
```

And when I did it, there wasn't any mistakes, but instead of page, I just saw nothing, everything disappeared.
So, on which step I do mistakes and how I can solve it?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: That is why: https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-country-select/issues/1